# source code compiling error on MacOsX 10.8

Tags: macos, compiler-errors

I tried to compile a pass source code in my MacOSX 10.8. I first had the problem that

```
iMac-de-Anne:pass_v1.2 elenacapel$ make
g++ src/pass.cpp -O9 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -DSHRIMP_BUGS=OFF -static -D NOSERVER -lpthread -o bin/pass
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

But I could install the libraries missing by installing Xcode.

Now I have a different error while trying to compile the source code:

```
iMac-de-Anne:pass_v1.2 elenacapel$ make
g++ src/pass.cpp -O9 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -DSHRIMP_BUGS=OFF -static -D NOSERVER -lpthread -o bin/pass
error: invalid value '9' in '-O9'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any helpful tips?

Comment: The flag -O in g++ sets the level of optimization for the compiler. The maximum level is 3. You are probably looking for '-O3'

Comment: Replace `-O9` with `-O3` in the `Makefile` file. `-O` should only take an argument from 0 to 3.

Comment: I changed the '-O9' with '-03' and it worked partially. I still don't manage to compile the program. Now I have the following error:ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: I changed the '-O9' with '-03' and it worked partially. I still don't manage to compile the program. Now I have the following error:>ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
>clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>make: *** [all] Error 1